# Solving a implicit, recursive function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

Assuming $F(0,0)=0$, can I solve $F(F(x,y),y)=0$ for $y=f(x)$ near $(0,0).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote
$$
G(x,y) = F(F(x,y), y) \tag{1}.
$$

Implicit function theorem says that there is a unique solution $y = f(x)$ in some neighborhood of $(0,0)$ if
$$
\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}(0,0) \neq 0.
$$

Using (1) and chain rule we get
$$
\frac{\partial G}{\partial y} = F'_1 \cdot \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}.
$$

Here by $F'_1$ we denoted partial derivative of $F$ with respect to first variable.

Can you proceed now?

Comment: Your notation should be consistent. If $F$ is a function of $(x,y)$ and you're writing $\partial F/\partial y$, then you should write $\partial F/\partial x$ instead of $F'_1$. But you should make clear where you're evaluating these partial derivatives — or else confusion and wrong results may follow.

Comment: I intentionally use this notation to make OP think at which point this derivative should be evaluated